# FIle transfer - XML based notifications and data exchange

Tags: java, android, xml, sockets, p2p

I am playing around with Android Sockets and I currently I am trying to send a file via WiFi. I have a simple protocol that uses few notification classes. Everything works OK on Java client and Java server, but I want to do the same thing with C# (or C++) server/client and Java client/server. I need to decide how to serialize my notification data.

I was thinking about XML format. It would contain a notification ID, client ID and some data (i.ex. chunk of a file).

How can I save a chunk of a file (or any byte array) into a XML file (or text based file)?

Maybe I am thinking completely wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your data through a [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoder and then stick that data into a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section in your xml file.  [Apache](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) makes a Base64 library for Java.  I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard to find one for C#/C++.

Comment: @Robert Massaioli Also I have question to more experienced coders. Is this XML approach OK? I mean, am I going a right way to transfer a file from C# client to JAVA(Android) server?

Comment: XML is a good choice for passing platform agnostic data around.  It is what I would use if I had the requirements you describe.

Comment: Ok, I have implemeted a prototype protocol and it is working, but it seems kinda slow (maybe because all that encoding and decoding). Also it generates twice data size than it is needed. I am not sure if this is good approach. I am starting to think about binary notifications format, but I am not sure what problems I might see.